# Cannot update a column in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, multiple-columns

I cannot update my remarks column using the below query

```
update Customers
set customers.Remarks = remarks_stg.remarks
from 
    (select remarks 
     from remarks_stg) remarks_stg
where customers.Remarks = 'updateme'
```

The query executed successfully but the `remarks` column in customers was not updated.

I am trying to update `remarks` column in `customers` table from `remarks` column of `remarks_Stg` table.

Regards

Updated
[image]

Comment: What is the relation between Remarks table and Customers table?

Comment: Show sample data please.

Comment: @Shruti . No relations is there

Comment: If there is nothing to link the two then you cannot really do what you are trying since you are going to be updating customers.remarks to equal the first value in remarks_stg.

Comment: @Bodhi How do you know which 'remarks' to use for updating customers table?

Comment: @Shruti ...   what i was trying to accomplish is, i have to merge or update all the records from remarks_stg to customers table in the same order

Comment: @OwainEsau .. is it possible to merge remarks table into the customers table.

Comment: @Bodhi And the order is defined by? Row number? Some sort of ID? It would be clearer if you included sample input and output in the question.

Comment: @Shruti The only way to do this via a set order of rows is if you have them ordered and use DENSE_RANK but this would also require there to be exactly the same amount of records in each table

Comment: @Shruti .. can I create a primary key column called ID in remarks_Stg and link it to the customers table as a foreign key.. Now i dont have any relationship between them

Comment: @OwainEsau .. This sounds fine..  how to do it here in my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the data from the following query is not returning.

```
SELECT * FROM customers
Where customers.Remarks = 'update'
```

If the data was returning, the update would be done

By the way, there is a logic error in the query. You do not specify which record you want to record from the `remarks_stg` table.

You need to specify the relationship between the two tables in the where condition.

```
Update Customers
Set customers.Remarks = remarks_stg.remarks
From
     (Select remarks, YourRelationshipColumn from remarks_stg) remarks_stg
Where
     Customers.Remarks = 'updateme' AND
     Customers.YourRelationshipColumn = Remarks_Stg.YourRelationshipColumn
```

If you do not specify the relationship, the first record in the `remarks_stg` table will be retrieved.

**Update**

You can do this using `ROW_NUMBER()`. You should write a unique column from the `Customer` table.

```
UPDATE Customers
SET Remarks = RESULT.remarks
FROM
(
    SELECT A.CustomerID, B.remarks
    FROM
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RowId, * FROM Customers) A INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RowId, * FROM remarks_stg) B ON A.RowId = B.RowId
) RESULT
WHERE
    Customers.CustomerID = RESULT.CustomerID
```

**Note**: the relationship between the two tables has to be. If not, you have to change the structure.

Comment: i have around  91 customers , is it possible to update or merge the remarks column directly to the customers table.

Comment: Nothing is returning .. SELECT * FROM customers Where customers.Remarks = 'updateme' – Bodhi 5 mins ago

Comment: @Bodhi If the data is not returning, you can not update. Which customers would you like to update? Do you want to update a single column by combining all the lines in the remarks table?

Comment: i want to update all the column in customers table with the same order like remarks (remarks_Stg) column ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138340/discussion-between-cer-and-bodhi).

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
update Customers
SET customers.Remarks= remarks_stg.remarks
from remarks_stg
where customers.Remarks='updateme'
```

But it will use first value from table remarks_stg so try to add another condition like this:

```
AND remarks_stg.Id = 2
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me.  also, please note that both tables don't have any relations.  they are independent tables now i want to use the records of remarks_stg to update customers table

Comment: does
    SELECT *
    FROM Customers c
    WHERE c.Remarks = 'updateme' return something?

Comment: Nothing is returning ..   SELECT * FROM customers
Where customers.Remarks = 'updateme'

Comment: Replace 'updateme' with the value you want to update. or remove condition. note that if you remove the WHERE clause the entire column customer.remarks will be updated.

Comment: Its not updating with or without where clause.

Answer (score 1):

update Customers

SET Remarks = (select remarks from remarks_stg)

where Remarks = 'updateme'

OR

update Customers

SET Remarks = (select remarks from remarks_stg WHERE id = [PARTICULAR ID] )

where Remarks = 'updateme'

Comment: This doesnt work for me. also, please note that both tables don't have any relations. they are independent tables now i want to use the records of remarks_stg to update customers table –

Answer (score 1):

You will need the "Customers" table in the From Clause and join it with your "remarks_stg" table. Replace the "SomeColumn" below with your column matching between two tables.

```
update Customers
set customers.Remarks = remarks_stg.remarks
from Customers 
Inner Join 
    (select remarks 
     from remarks_stg) remarks_stg
     On Customers.SomeColumn = remarks_stg.SomeColumn
where customers.Remarks = 'updateme'
```